# BeautifulSoup: scraping for a span gives me a result, for another span it gives "None"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am coding a scraper for Etsy and when I scrape the span for reviews I get the right output. However when I scrape for the span with the price it gives me only None values and I don't understand why. If someone could help, it would be great!

```
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each listing card
divs = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "v2-listing-card__shop"})

for i in divs:

    shop = i.p.text
    reviews = i.find("span", {"class" : "text-body-smaller text-gray-lighter display-inline-block vertical-align-middle icon-b-1"})
    prices = i.find("span", {"class" : "currency-value"})



    print shop
    print reviews.text
    print prices
```

Here are the two span elements as on the website:

```
    <div class="v2-listing-card__info">
<p class="text-gray text-truncate mb-xs-0 text-body">
                Blush Watercolor Flowers &amp; Leaves with Different Shades Clipart Separate Elements Hand Painted Commercial Use | S15 Fairy Tale
            </p>
<div class="v2-listing-card__shop">
<p class="text-gray-lighter text-body-smaller display-inline-block mr-xs-1">PatishopArt</p>
<div class="v2-listing-card__rating icon-t-2">
<div class="stars-svg stars-smaller ">
<input name="initial-rating" type="hidden" value="5"/>
<input name="rating" type="hidden" value="5"/>
<span class="screen-reader-only">5 out of 5 stars</span>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="rating lit rating-first icon-b-2" data-rating="1">
<span class="etsy-icon stars-svg-star" title="Disappointed"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="3 3 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.985,10.36a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.477-0.352H14.157L12.488,4.366a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.962,0l-1.67,5.642H4.5a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.279.911L8.53,13.991l-1.5,5.328a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.741.6l4.231-2.935,4.215,2.935a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.743-0.6l-1.484-5.328,4.306-3.074A0.5,0.5,0,0,0,19.985,10.36Z"></path></svg></span>
<div class="rating lit" data-rating="2">
<span class="etsy-icon stars-svg-star" title="Not a fan"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="3 3 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.985,10.36a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.477-0.352H14.157L12.488,4.366a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.962,0l-1.67,5.642H4.5a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.279.911L8.53,13.991l-1.5,5.328a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.741.6l4.231-2.935,4.215,2.935a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.743-0.6l-1.484-5.328,4.306-3.074A0.5,0.5,0,0,0,19.985,10.36Z"></path></svg></span>
<div class="rating lit" data-rating="3">
<span class="etsy-icon stars-svg-star" title="It's okay"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="3 3 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.985,10.36a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.477-0.352H14.157L12.488,4.366a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.962,0l-1.67,5.642H4.5a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.279.911L8.53,13.991l-1.5,5.328a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.741.6l4.231-2.935,4.215,2.935a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.743-0.6l-1.484-5.328,4.306-3.074A0.5,0.5,0,0,0,19.985,10.36Z"></path></svg></span>
<div class="rating lit" data-rating="4">
<span class="etsy-icon stars-svg-star" title="Like it"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="3 3 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.985,10.36a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.477-0.352H14.157L12.488,4.366a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.962,0l-1.67,5.642H4.5a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.279.911L8.53,13.991l-1.5,5.328a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.741.6l4.231-2.935,4.215,2.935a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.743-0.6l-1.484-5.328,4.306-3.074A0.5,0.5,0,0,0,19.985,10.36Z"></path></svg></span>
<div class="rating lit" data-rating="5">
<span class="etsy-icon stars-svg-star" title="Love it"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewbox="3 3 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.985,10.36a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.477-0.352H14.157L12.488,4.366a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.962,0l-1.67,5.642H4.5a0.5,0.5,0,0,0-.279.911L8.53,13.991l-1.5,5.328a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.741.6l4.231-2.935,4.215,2.935a0.5,0.5,0,0,0,.743-0.6l-1.484-5.328,4.306-3.074A0.5,0.5,0,0,0,19.985,10.36Z"></path></svg></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<span class="text-body-smaller text-gray-lighter display-inline-block vertical-align-middle icon-b-1">(110)</span>
</div>
</div>
<p class="n-listing-card__price text-gray strong mt-xs-0">
<span class="currency-symbol">$</span><span class="currency-value">6.60</span>
</p>
<!-- This shows Free shipping on its own line , we only show it if it wasn't shown above -->
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, it is correct 'value' - I just tried with the 'symbol' to test it and forgot to change the code back. With the 'symbol' it still gives me None values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a URL for the html or a more complete html snippet please? Do the span elements really not close properly?

Comment: Thanks! The spans do close, I just couldn't post it as code and deleted the slashes. I will try to post the snippet

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking in divs of type listing-card__shop but it looks to me as if the span in question, is outside of those divs

Comment: Maybe you are right. I did a find_all for spans on the whole parsed page and it found them. But still the span is in this div. Anyway thanks for helping me go forward. I will change the code now!

Comment: I think it's part of the div with this class:  v2-listing-card__info

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I double-checked and found my mistake. Thank you very much!